# Вывести элементы матрицы по диагоналям

Tags: массивы, pascal

Вводится размерность матрицы(от 1 до 100).
Вводится сама матрица.
Вывести в строку элементы по диагоналям слева направо, снизу вверх.
Пример:

```
5
```

//ввод размера матрицы

```
1  3  6  10  15
2  5  9  14  19
4  8  13 18  22
7  12 17 21  24
11 16 20 23  25
```

//вывод

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 0):

i = счётчик рядов

j = счётчик столбцов

n = к-во рядов так же столбцов

arr = новый массив в котором добавляешь нужные значения

к = счётчик ячеек в массиве arr

при перебора матрицы от к-ву рядов к 1 и от к-ву столбцов к 1, проверяйте если счётчик рядов + счётчик столбцов ровно к-ву рядов +1 тогда это нужный вам элемент (по диагонали с низу в верх и с лево на право)

if (i+j = n+1) then arr[k] = m[i][j];

ниже матрица (вместо значений ячеек, счётчики i,j для ясности)...

m[i][j]

11 12 13 14 15

21 22 23 24 25

31 32 33 34 35

41 42 43 44 45

51 52 53 54 55

после перебора, выявите на экран массив arr

Comment: if (i+j = n+1) then arr[k] = m[i][j]; 
данное условие выполняется лишь на главной/побочной диагонали, в зависимости от того как обходить.

Answer (score 0):

Для произвольной матрицы, алгоритм называется diagonal traversal. Ниже мой вариант реализации.

```py
rows = 4
cols = 3
arr = [[1, 3,  6],
       [2, 5,  9],
       [4, 8, 11],
       [7,10, 12]]

# There will be ROW+COL-1 diagonal lines 
for i in range(1, cols + rows):
    start_column = max(0, i - rows)
    end_column = min(i, cols)
    for j in range(start_column, end_column):
        print(arr[i - j - 1][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Вывод:

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
10 11 
12
```